# Error in Inception retraining

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I'm not using Docker. So I had to change url of retrain.py. I'm running this command from home. I have tf_files folder containing flower_photos and inception folder in it.

```
sudo python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

I get the following error: [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nykHk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** it by simply downloading **tensorflow** in home ~ folder instead /dist-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Inception file download got corrupted. You should download the file manually and paste it in the tf_files folder.